# swapbuffers minifilter problems

Tags: driver, minifilter

I implemented a minifilter driver using the swapbuffers example. I made two changes:

- attach only to \Device\HarddiskVolume3
- encryption XORing with 0xFF

Encryption works, but the volume3 (which in my system is E:) not working. E: is not recognized file system. `chkdsk E:` results all boot sectors corrupted message.

After investigations (using procmon.exe): the chkdsk.exe creates a shadow copy of volume. If the driver attaches the shadow copy too the `chkdsk E:` is OK, the filesystem is perfect. But E: remains unrecognized.

Any idea what I should change?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no simple mistake was made, that is, the volume was unmounted, you added the filter, and remounted, obviously the mount/filesystem is not using your filter.

I noticed a comment in the example code about "not for kernel mode drivers".

What you want to research is "whole disk encryption".  A google search AND search on: `windows whole disk encryption` will help.

In particular, `TrueCrypt` does what you want.  Since it is open source, and is available on sourceforge.net, you could download the source and figure out how to hook your stuff in by learning how `TrueCrypt` does it.

Just one problem:  `TrueCrypt` has security gaps, so the sourceforge.net page is now just migration info to `BitLocker`.  But, it still exists and other pages have been created where you can get it.  Notably, a fork of `TrueCrypt` is `VeraCrypt`

Just one of the pages in the search is: http://www.howtogeek.com/203708/3-alternatives-to-the-now-defunct-truecrypt-for-your-encryption-needs/

**UPDATE**

Note: After I wrote this update, I realized that there may be hope ... So, keep reading.

Minifilter *appears* to be for *filesystems* but not underlying storage.  It *may* work, you just need to find a lower level hook.  What about filter stack `altitute`?  Here's a link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  It also has documentation on `fltmc` and the `!fltkd` debugger extension

In this [short] blog:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erick/archive/2006/03/27/562257.aspx it says:

> The Filter Manager was meant to create a simple mechanism for drivers to filter file system operations: file system minifilter drivers.  File system minifilter driver are located between the I/O manager and the base filesystem, not between the filesystem and the storage driver(s) like legacy file system filter drivers.

Figuring out what that means will help.  Is the hook point between FS and I/O manager [which I don't know about] sufficient?  Or, do you need to hook between filesystem and storage drivers [implying legacy filter]?

My suspicion is that a "legacy" driver filter may be what you need, if the minifilter does not have something that can do the same.

Since your hooks need to work on *unmounted* storage so that `chkdsk` will work, this may imply the legacy filter.  On the other hand, you mentioned that you were able to hook the shadow copy and it worked for chkdsk.  That implies minifilter has the right stuff.

Here's a link that I think is a bit more informative:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2013/03/25/understanding-file-system-minifilter-and-legacy-filter-load-order.aspx  It has a direct example about the `altitute` of an encryption filter.  You just may need more hook points and to lower the altitude of your minifilter

**UPDATE #2**

Swapbuffers just hooks a few things:  `IRP_MJ_READ`, `IRP_MJ_WRITE`, `IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`.  These are file I/O related, not device I/O related.  The example is fine, just not necessarily for your purposes.

The link I gave you to fltmc is one page in MS's entire reference for filters.  If you meander around that, you'll find more interesting things like `IoGetDeviceAttachmentBaseRef`, `IoGetDiskDeviceObject`.  You need to find the object for the device and filter its I/O operations.

I think that you'll have to read the reference material in addition to examples.  As I've said previously, your filter needs to hook more or different things.

In the VeraCrypt source, the Driver subdirectory is an example of the types of things you may need to do.  In DriveFilter.c, it uses `IRP_MJ_READ` but also uses `IRP_MN_START_DEVICE` [A hook when the device is started].

Seriously, this may be more work than you imagine.  Is this just for fun, or is this just a test case for a much larger project?

Comment: I am totally confused. Everywhere I read that minifilter driver model is the fututre. But it is unsuitable to make this simple task: whole volume encryption. Some comments: using DebugView I saw that my filter was actually used. "Not for kernel mode drivers" was disabling a warning only. I examined VeraCrypt source but I thought that it is too complicated. My task is to develop a simple whole volume encryptor driver. The encrypting is simple, the key holding device (special token) needs special development.

Comment: I mentioned hooking the shadow copy. It was totally guessing. How can I determine from a shadow copy that it is connected to volume3, so I have to decrypt its data? By the way why does exist the swapbuffers sample if it is useless?

Comment: You are right: test case for a larger project. Task: some predefined volume _whole volume encrypting_. Predefined means that I can even write into the .inf file. Encrypt algo will be some wellknown but key-holder token needs special programming. I saw three ways: 1) starting from a suitable sample (this was the `swapbuffers`) 2) develop from scratch a KDMF driver 3) "to pare" an open source sw like VeraCrypt. The order means the difficulty (I think).